# Does every element of a cyclic subgroup generate the subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was just wondering this. It's false correct? A (as in a single) element generates a cyclic subgroup, but not every element of a cyclic subgroup generates said cylcic subgroup correct?

Comment: as far as false things go, this is really really really false.

Answer (score 4):

This is false: Choose *any* cyclic group of composite order and it'll give a counterexample.

Comment: Cool I just wanted to confirm this. Thank you